# How to do a Stupid IfLessThan in Django?

Tags: django, if-statement

So Django apparently has a "smart `if`" in later versions, but our version is apparently not so smart.

How do you do a stupid version of `if a < b` in Django (for the lack of a better word)?

Comment: Are you talking about `if` in templates & what version are you using?

Comment: @manji: Yeah I'm talking about the equivalent of `{% if a < b %}`. I'm using version 1.2.5.

Comment: Are you sure? Here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#new-in-1-2-smart-if, "smart-if" was added to 1.2 release => 1.2.5 also.

Comment: @manji: I checked `django.VERSION` and that's what it told me... and smart if's don't work for me. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standalone [smart_if templatetag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/).  This was the base code that got merged into trunk.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it. Just wondering: was it originally impossible to compare two values in django?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  You could only test equality(`{% ifequal %}`) and inequality(`{% ifnotequal %}`).

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to do the logic in the python view code and not the template.

Suppose you want to display a warning if the user's age is less than 18. Instead of doing the test in the template, compute a new variable in the view called 'underage' as 'age < 18'. Pass that to the template and then test with the standard 'if' tag.